# Can we assign value to `a` if it is borrowed?

Tags: rust

this is simple code which shows error `cannot assign to a because it is borrowed assi gnment to borrowed a occurs here`. Can it be possible to assign value if it is borrowed?

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = 20;
    let b = &a;

    a = 20;
    println!("{}, {}", a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Rust* enforces "multiple readers or single writer" rule at compile time. As long as there is mutable reference to a value you cannot use the owner until the mutable reference goes away. Similarly as ***long as there is multiple shared references to value not even it's owner can modify it*.** For example, this would compile.

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = 20;
    {
        let b = &a;
        println!("{}", b);
    } // Shared reference goes out of scope here
    a = 20;
    println!("{}", a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not without [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html).

Disallowing mutation of a value that is borrowed prevents many different kinds of bugs.  For example, you cannot push onto a `Vec` while you have a shared reference to a value in the `Vec`.  This seems arbitrary, but if pushing causes an internal reallocation, previously-dispensed references would become dangling.

Here's what the interior mutability approach would look like:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

fn main() {
    let a = Cell::new(20);
    let b = &a;

    a.set(10);
    println!("{}, {}", a.get(), b.get());
}
```

Note `a` doesn't even have to be declared `mut`, because cells can be mutated through a shared reference.